# How to add multiple circle on circular progress bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, swift4.2

I have implemented circular progress bar. but now i want to add multiple circles on progress bar. like below image

[image]

I have implemented below code

```
let rect = rectForShape()
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:rect.midX , y: rect.midY), radius: CGFloat(10), startAngle: CGFloat(50), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
// Change the fill color
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
// You can change the stroke color
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
// You can change the line width
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: Welcome to this community! Would you please add what kind of problem you bumped in and what kind of action you wish from your readers? This will help them figure out a precise answer more easily and quicker.

Comment: We need much more detail to try and help. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].